# How to delete the files generated in the docker container outside the container?

Tags: docker

I need to compile some programs using files in a docker container. Once compiled, the container is no longer used.

Therefore I always use the following command. `docker run --rm -v my_file:docker_file my_images my_command`

But I find that there are always some problems.

1. For example, take a simple C language program that outputs "hello, world" as an example.

```
    docker run -it --rm -v /home/cuiyujie/workspace/workGem5/gem5/hello.c:/home/cuiyujie/workspace/workGem5/gem5/hello.c -v /home/cuiyujie/workspace/workGem5/gem5/build:/home/cuiyujie/workspace/workGem5/gem5/build  gerrie/gem5-bare-env
```

After entering the container, execute `gcc hello.c -o hello`, `cp hello build`.

I found outside the container that the hello file belongs to root.

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root     16696 2月  23 10:23 hello*

I don't have permission to delete it. what should I do to make it become the permissions of the host user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your container as your own UID, files created in the host volumes will be owned by your UID. That comes with the disclaimer that your container needs to be designed to run as a user other than root (e.g. not need access to files owned by root inside the container). Here's an example of running as your uid/gid and full access to your home directory using bash on Linux (the `$(id -u)` expansion may not work in other environments):

```sh
docker container run \
  -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -w "$(pwd)" \
  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro \
  -v /etc/group:/etc/group:ro \
  -v "$HOME:$HOME" \
  <your_image>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chown` to change the ownership of a file. You'll need permission to run it with `sudo` though.

```
$ sudo chown $USER hello
```

If you also want to change the group of the file to your primary group, you can put a `.` after the user:

```
$ sudo chown $USER. hello
```